# Box2d Edgeshape doesn't rotate

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx, polygon, physics

I'm using Libgdx's port of box2d.  I'm creating an edge shape, but it does not rotate upon collision with other polygons.  Why is this?

Here's my code for setting up the edge shape.

```
float x = 3;
float y = 10;
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(x, y);

Body body = this.world.createBody(bodyDef);
MassData massdata = new MassData();
massdata.center.set(1,1);
massdata.mass = 10;
body.setMassData(massdata);

FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
EdgeShape shape = new EdgeShape();
shape.set(0, 0, 2, 2);
fixtureDef.shape= shape;
fixtureDef.friction = 1;
fixtureDef.restitution = .5f;
fixtureDef.density = 10;
body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martijn said, I calculate and set mass data of the body.  To do this, I calculate the center of mass assuming uniform density.  I am using LIBGDX and so I needed a way to do this in java.  I wrote the routine using Box2D's source.  Feel free to use it for whatever you like.

EdgeShapes do not have mass, and so do not behave physically.  To cause this kind of behavior, manually calculation was necessary.

```
public static MassData calculateMassData(List<Vector2> vertices,
        float density) {
    float k_inv3 = 1.0f / 3.0f;
    float area = 0.0f;
    float I = 0.0f;
    Vector2 center = new Vector2();

    Vector2 s = new Vector2();
    for (int i = 0, size = vertices.size(); i < size; i++) {
        s.add(vertices.get(i));
    }
    s.div(vertices.size());

    for (int i = 0, size = vertices.size(); i < size; ++i) {
        // Triangle vertices.
        Vector2 e1 = new Vector2(vertices.get(i));
        e1.sub(s);
        Vector2 e2 = new Vector2(i + 1 < size ? vertices.get(i + 1)
                : vertices.get(0));
        e2.sub(s);

        float D = e1.crs(e2);

        float triangleArea = 0.5f * D;
        area += triangleArea;

        // Area weighted centroid
        center.add(e1.cpy().add(e2).mul(k_inv3).mul(triangleArea));

        float ex1 = e1.x, ey1 = e1.y;
        float ex2 = e2.x, ey2 = e2.y;

        float intx2 = ex1 * ex1 + ex2 * ex1 + ex2 * ex2;
        float inty2 = ey1 * ey1 + ey2 * ey1 + ey2 * ey2;

        I += (0.25f * k_inv3 * D) * (intx2 + inty2);
    }

    MassData data = new MassData();
    // Total mass
    data.mass = density * area;

    center.mul(1.0f / area);
    data.center.set(center.cpy().add(s));
    // Inertia tensor relative to the local origin (point s).
    data.I = density * I;

    // Shift to center of mass then to original body origin.
    data.I += data.mass
            * (data.center.dot(data.center) - center.dot(center));
    data.I = (data.I);
    return data;
}
```

2 limitations of edge shapes:

1. Edge shapes do not collide with other edge shapes
2. Edge shapes are not normal polygons. There's no real outside/inside definitions for any polygons built using only edge shapes.

Because of #2, other bodies can wind up inside of polygons built with edge shapes.

Because of #1, I took a different approach and constructed my polygon using a series of narrow rectangles.  This is working well, but unfortunately does not solve #2.

I am not wanting to use PolygonShape for fixtures because the polygon I am attempting to model is complex.  It can have hundreds of vertices.

I have tried triangulating my polygon and creating fixtures from each of these triangles.  Unfortunately often the resulting triangle's area is too small for Box2D, and causes exceptions with box2d.

I am open to other solutions here.

Comment: Are talking about EdgeShapes or Edge Chains? Your code makes me think you are working with EdgeChains, while you use the term EdgeShape. If I'm right, do you think you can make dynamic concave polygons in Box2D?

Comment: In LIBGDX port of box2d EdgeChains are not available. No lol, I don't think I can create concave polygons. As I said, I'm triangulating my polygon.  Perhaps that wasn't clear.  I triangulate my complex concave polygon in order to represent it in Box2D using a series of triangle PolygonShape fixtures.

Answer (score 3):

That is because an Edge Shape in Box2D is meant to create static scenery. It simply cannot move due to dynamics. I guess kinematic would work. This is logic, because an EdgeShape has no mass, since it has no surface (or volume if you would consider the 2D world as 3D with a fixed depth).

Here is an excerpt taken from the manual, which confirms my initial thoughts:

> Edge shapes are line segments. These are provided to assist in making
>   a free-form static environment for your game. A major limitation of
>   edge shapes is that they can collide with circles and polygons but not
>   with themselves. The collision algorithms used by Box2D require that
>   at least one of two colliding shapes have volume. Edge shapes have no
>   volume, so edge-edge collision is not possible.

Comment: I've already solved this, I'll post my solution sometime tonight.  Edge Shapes can in fact rotate and behave physically.  But thanks!

Comment: How? By manually setting the b2MassData struct variables instead of constructing it the official way?

Comment: Again, ill post my solution later. Critique then.

Comment: I'm sorry. Just interested :P

Comment: No its fine, I'm sorry just busy.  I'll post it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#setFixedRotation%28boolean%29

```
body.setFixedRotation(false)
```

Also your friction is too high. Try 0.6f

Comment: Fixed rotation is set to false by default, but i tried explicitly setting it anyway. Also changed the friction, it didnt help.